# Dependence of perimeter of a triangle on the movement of one of its vertices

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Can someone provide a rigorous or at least reasonable argument for why the perimeter of the triangle $\Delta PAB$ in the below image varies as the point $P$ moves horizontally?
[image]
The [solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2000_AMC_10_Problems/Problem_5) just tells me to consider the far end of the line, which enables me to intuit the idea, but not really think about it "rigorously". In other words, how can I prove without doubt that the perimeter varies in this case. I know that AB is always constant but I have no clue on where to start!

This is part (b) of [2000 AMC 10 Problems/Problem 5](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2000_AMC_10_Problems/Problem_5).

Comment: The question does not require you to prove that perimeter is different for every point $P$ on the line parallel to $AB$. Even if you show that it is true for any two points on the line, that suffices. So take a point $P$ such that $BP \perp AB$ and then choose a new point $P$ to the right of it.

Comment: More rigorously. Consider any position of P. Let perimeter for this position is $p_1$. This perimeter is greater than distance from P to line AB. The circle of radius $p_1$ with center A have two common points with P-line, parallel to AB. Let move P to any of these points. Then perimeter in new position is greater than PA=$p_1$. Therefore, perimeter cannot be constant.

Comment: You could also reflect $B$ across the line to get a point $B'$, and observe that $PA+PB=PA+PB'$ equals the distance from $A$ to $B'$ when the triangle is isosceles, and for any other triangle you get a path from $A$ to $B'$ that is not straight, so it's longer. A fun consequence is that even if the line is not parallel, you can find the smallest perimeter this way.

Comment: @MathLover I don't quite understand your argument, take a point to the right and then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: TrianglePerimeter]

Our aim is to express the perimeter of the triangle $PAB$ in terms of its apex angle $\pmb{\theta}$. We denote the area of the triangle $PAB$ as $\Delta$, which you know by now is a constant.  Similarly the base of the triangle, i.e. $AB$, is also a constant.

We are also aware that, if we want to keep the apex angle constant, we have to move the vertex $P$ along the circumference of the circumcircle of $\triangle PAB$. According to OP’s problem statement, $P$ is shifted along a line parallel to $AB$. Such movements of $P$ do not hold the value of $\theta$ constant.

$AH$ is the altitude dropped from the vertex $A$ to the side $PB$. Therefore, we have,
$$AH = PA\times\sin\left(\theta\right) = 2PA\times\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\times\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right). \tag{1}$$

Using(1), we can obtain an expression for the area of the triangle $PAB$ as shown below.

$$\Delta =\dfrac{1}{2}PB\times AH = PB\times PA\times\sin\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)\times\cos\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right) \tag{2}$$

When we apply cosine rule to $\triangle PAB$, we get,
$$PA^2 + PB^2 -2PA\times PB\times\cos\left(\theta\right)= AB^2, \quad\text{where}\quad \theta \le 2\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{AB}{2PQ}\right).$$

This can be manipulated to derive an expression for $PA+PB$ as shown below.
$$PA^2 + PB^2 + 2PA\times PB = AB^2 + 2PA\times PB\times\Bigl(1+\cos\left(\theta\right)\Bigr)$$

$$PA + PB = \sqrt{AB^2 + 4PA\times PB\times\cos^2\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)}\tag{3}$$

Now, we replace $PA\times PB$ on LHS of (3) using (2).
$$PA + PB = \sqrt{AB^2 + 4\Delta\times\cot\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)} \tag{4}$$

According to (4), the perimeter of $\triangle PAB$ is equal to,
$$PA + PB +AB =  \sqrt{AB^2 + 4\Delta\times\cot\left(\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right)} +AB$$

This equality shows that the perimeter depends on $\theta$, which is a variable quantity as shown above. Therefore, the perimeter itself varies as $P$ traverses along a line parallel to $AB$.

Comment: Hold on, for (3) how did you get PA + PB = ... from PA^2 = +PB^2 = ... ?

Comment: I left it for you to work out. Since you have requested, I added the missing step of the derivation of (3).

Answer (score 0):

suppose the perimeter is a constant.
then $a+b$ is a constant.
let $s$ be the semiperimeter.
let $c$ be the length of AB.
the area is a constant, so by Heron's formula,
$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$ is a constant.
$s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)$ is a constant.
$(s-a)(s-b)$ is a constant.
$s^2-(a+b)s+ab$ is a constant.
$ab$ is a constant.
we can use the quadratic formula to solve for $a,b$
$a,b$ has $\leq 2$ values each.
by SSS, there are at most 2 triangles with sides $a,b,c$.
but there are infinitely many incongruent triangles as $P$ is moved along the line.
contradiction.

alternatively, since PA + PB is a constant, the locus of P is an ellipse, not a line.

Comment: > There are infinitely many incongruent triangles as PP is moved along the line
You still need to prove it

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be the line parallel to AB that contains $P$. We prove this by showing that for any real number $K$, there is a point $P'$ on $L$ such that the perimeter of $P'AB$ is at least $K$. This suffices to answer the question.

Let us write for any line-segment $S$ the length of $S$ as $\ell(S)$. Then let $P'$ be a point on $L$ such that the distance from $P$ to $P'$ on $L$ is at least $K+\ell(PA)$, or equivalently,  the inequality $\ell(PP') \ge K+\ell(PA)$ holds. Then as the shortest distance between the two points $P$ and $P'$ in a plain is a straight line, the following inequality holds:
$$\ell(PP') \le \ell(PA)+\ell(AP').$$
As $\ell(PP')$ is $K+\ell(PA)$, it follows from this that $\ell(AP')$ must be at least $K$.

However, the perimeter of triangle $ABP'$ is greater than $\ell(AP')\ge K$, so the perimeter of triangle $P'AB$ is indeed greater than $K$, so as observed in the top paragraph, the result follows from this.